# Use Xming without putty

Tags: linux, ssh, xorg, xming

I currently do have putty and xming working correctly in tandem, however I don't really enjoy using putty's interface and the first command I run is `gnome-terminal &` and get my favorite terminal emulater pulled up. I can also do this with MobaXterm with the desired results.

I have ming ssh installed on my PC and also have it added to my env path so I can ssh to and from my *nix boxes without trouble from command prompt or windows run. However I can't use terminal ssh and xming in tandem. So when I try:

`ssh -X myname@ipaddress gnome-terminal`

I get the error `Failed to parse arguments: Cannot open display:`

Is there any way I can get these to interop fully? (The ultimate goal is to create a desktop shortcut or assign a keyboard shortcut to do this) Thanks to all in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I just tossed XMing. It wasn't working correctly, regardless of the various directions I followed and research I did from various other sites (It must be something on my end, but I have no idea what). Instead I am using cygwin's version of x. I installed it after reading [this](http://aufather.wordpress.com/2012/02/12/cygwin-x-server-a-better-alternative-to-xming/) and it works.

The only thing that didn't work out of the box was setting the environment variable by running `export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0` in my .bashrc, as was stated in Rich Homolka's answer. For all my windows based prompts I added `DISPLAY` to my system environment variables and it works pretty much as expected.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I think the normal way of running Putty is with [X forwarding over ssh](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/). You could log onto your machine with Putty, then run `setsid gnome-terminal`, then you can close Putty.

That said, for various reasons (multi-user environent) I like to run it with the normal old TCP Listener running.

```
start XMing :0 -ac -from 0.0.0.0 +bs -clipboard  -multiwindow -nowinkill -logfile C:\temp\xming.log -logverbose 3
```

Then set your DISPLAY `export DISPLAY=:0`

Comment: Closing putty closes all gui's that it pulled up unfortunately.

As far as the second suggestion went, I ran `set DISPLAY=:0` and confirmed it was set by running `echo %DISPLAY` which correctly displayed `:0`.

However attempting to run `ssh -X myname@ipaddress gnome-terminal` gave me
`connect /tmp/.x11-unix/x0: Bad file number
Failed to parse arguments: Cannot open display:`

Comment: @SonofLysander this is a [bit](http://superuser.com/questions/236044/how-to-keep-a-remote-task-running-after-running-it-in-an-ssh-console) of a [FAQ](http://superuser.com/questions/172043/how-do-i-fork-a-process-that-doesnt-die-when-shell-exits), you can wrap the command you run with 'setsid' (my answer above edited with this change) or use other tricks like `disown`

Answer (score 0):

Use putty to build configuration that attaches to your server and starts your initial program.  Ideally using agent-based authentication.

Once you have your configuration profile built, then simply use plink to load your session.  With a command like `plink -load sessionname`

Finally start plink by writing a script using the Windows scripting host.  VBscript, or Javscript will do.  An [example script](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/xterm.js) is provided on the Xming page.  Pass the options to your [wshell.run command to hide the plink Window](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/wsh/17419).